# Error en la colocación de la leyenda y formato de un gráfico de Dumbbell

Tags: r

Me gustaíra realizar un Dumbbell gráfico pero no logro ni añadirle la leyenda ni ajustar a la derecha o izquierda los valores que corresponde a cada categoría.

Parto de este dataframe:

```
    groups_COPD_1 <- structure(data.frame(Episcan_I = c("21.5", "24.1", "10.1", "25.3", "0.0", "2.5", "21.5", "20.3", "68.4", "65.8"),
                                    gr = c("Degree of dyspnea Grade 2", "Expectoration","Degree of dyspnea Grade 3", "Chronic cough", 
                                           "Degree of dyspnea Grade 5", "Degree of dyspnea Grade 4", "Asthma", 
                                           "Chronic Bronchitis", "Wheezing", "Degree of dyspnea Grade 1"), 
                                    Episcan_II = c("59.5", "38.1", " 16.7", " 28.6", "  1.2", "  3.6", " 15.5", "  9.5", " 51.2", " 19.0")))
```

El cual le he dado formato a cada una de las columnas:

```
    groups_COPD_1$Episcan_I<-as.numeric(groups_COPD_1$Episcan_I)
    groups_COPD_1$Episcan_II<-as.numeric(groups_COPD_1$Episcan_II)
    groups_COPD_1$diff=sprintf("%f", as.numeric((groups_COPD_1$Episcan_II-groups_COPD_1$Episcan_I)))

    groups_COPD_1$diff<-as.numeric(groups_COPD_1$diff)
    groups_COPD_1 <- arrange(groups_COPD_1, desc(diff))
    groups_COPD_1$diff<-paste(groups_COPD_1$diff,"%")
    groups_COPD_1$gr <- factor(groups_COPD_1$gr, levels=rev(groups_COPD_1$gr))
```

Y he realizaro dicho gráfico, especificando que quiero la leyenda y que quiero los números a la derecha e izquierda de la linea de cada categoría

```
    g1<-groups_COPD_1 %>%
      ggplot(aes(x=Episcan_I,xend=Episcan_II,y=gr, group=gr))+
      geom_dumbbell(
        colour="#b2b2b2",
        colour_x ="#9fb059",
        colour_xend = "#edae52",
        size=5.0,
        dot_guide = TRUE,
        dot_guide_size = 0.15,
        dot_guide_colour = "#b2b2b2",
        show.legend = TRUE
      )




    percent_first <- function(x) {
      x <- sprintf("%0.1f%%", round(x, digits = 1))
      x
    }

    g1 + geom_text(data=groups_COPD_1, aes(x=Episcan_I, y=gr, label=percent_first(Episcan_I)),
                 color="#9fb059", size=5, vjust=2.5,hjust=0.5)+
       geom_text(data=groups_COPD_1, color="#edae52", size=5, vjust=2.5,hjust=0.5,
                 aes(x=Episcan_II, y=gr, label=percent_first(Episcan_II)))+ 

      theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))+
      geom_rect(data=groups_COPD_1, aes(xmin=70, xmax=75, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="#efefe3")+ 
      geom_text(data=groups_COPD_1, aes(label=diff, y=gr, x=72.5), fontface="bold", size=5)+
      geom_text(data=filter(groups_COPD_1, gr=="Degree of dyspnea Grade 2"), aes(x=72.5, y=gr, label="DIFF"),
                color="#7a7d7e", size=5, vjust=-2, fontface="bold")+
      scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(-3, 76))+
      scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.100,0))+
      geom_segment(data=groups_COPD_1, aes(y=gr, yend=gr, x=0, xend=1), color="#b2b2b2", size=0.15)+
      theme_bw()+
      theme(
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())+
      labs(
        title ="Change of respiratory symptoms between Episcan I and Episcan II in COPD patients",
        x="Percentage (%)", y="Respiratory symptoms",cex.lab=1
      )
```

Tras la aplicación de este código me queda esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La leyenda no se ha añadido y los números algunos aparecen a los lados pero otros se solapan.
¿Como puedo solucionar estos problemas?
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que consideras la "leyenda que no se ha añadido"?

Comment: Me refeie a que tras poner show.legend esta no aparece en el gráfico. Más bien que salga un punto de un color y otro de otro y que diga Episcan I e Episcan II

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos primero el tema de la "leyenda", ésta efectivamente debería aparecer cuando en el `geom_dumbbell()` indicas `show.legend = TRUE`, pero el problema es que ninguna de las estéticas que tienes genera una leyenda, en el caso de este `geom` pareciera que la estética que lo hace es `fill`. Por ejemplo, esto debería generarte una leyenda por cada `gr`

```
groups_COPD_1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Episcan_I, xend=Episcan_II, y = gr, fill=gr)) +
  geom_dumbbell(colour="#b2b2b2",
                colour_x ="#9fb059",
                colour_xend = "#edae52",
                size=5.0,
                dot_guide = TRUE,
                dot_guide_size = 0.15,
                dot_guide_colour = "#b2b2b2",
                show.legend = TRUE
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

El tema es que esto no es lo que buscas, lo que quieres es crear una leyenda con los valores `Episcan I` y `Episcan II`, y estas categorías no existen en el `data.frame` original, si tienes los valores en dos columnas pero no las categorías que podrías mapear a una leyenda. Por suerte, a) esta inquietud ya la tuvo alguien ([ver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44662488/6836377)) y b) `ggplot` es muy flexible y puedes combinar `geoms` que se mapeen estéticamente a datos distintos.

Lo primero es generar los datos para producir las leyendas:

```
groups_COPD_1 %>% 
  select(gr, Episcan_I, Episcan_II) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-gr) -> leyenda

head(leyenda)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  gr                        name       value
  <fct>                     <chr>      <dbl>
1 Degree of dyspnea Grade 2 Episcan_I   21.5
2 Degree of dyspnea Grade 2 Episcan_II  59.5
3 Expectoration             Episcan_I   24.1
4 Expectoration             Episcan_II  38.1
5 Degree of dyspnea Grade 3 Episcan_I   10.1
6 Degree of dyspnea Grade 3 Episcan_II  16.7
```

Ahora, con estos datos, podemos rehacer un poco tu código, para el ejemplo lo voy a mantener lo más simple posible. La idea es distribuir los mapeos generales en `ggplot()` y los particulares en cada `geom()`. Las leyendas la vamos a mapear a los nuevos datos, pero a través de un `geom_point()` que se posicionan en los mismos lugares y con los mismos colores del `geom_dumbbell()`:

```
groups_COPD_1 %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y=gr)) +
  geom_point(data = leyenda, aes(x = value, color = name), size=5) +
  geom_dumbbell(mapping = aes(x=Episcan_I, xend=Episcan_II, y=gr),
                colour="#b2b2b2",
                colour_x ="#9fb059",
                colour_xend = "#edae52",
                size=5.0,
                dot_guide = TRUE,
                dot_guide_size = 0.15,
                dot_guide_colour = "#b2b2b2",
                show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("#9fb059", "#edae52"))
```

El resultado es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Con respecto a tu otra pregunta, el solapamiento de los porcentajes, te comento que solo lo noté cuando los valores son muy "cercanos", para lo cual mi sugerencia es o achicar el tamaño de la letra o bien ajustar la posición de un valor por encima de la barra y del otro por abajo. Finalmente tu código podría quedar así:

```
groups_COPD_1 %>% 
  select(gr, Episcan_I, Episcan_II) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-gr) -> leyenda

groups_COPD_1 %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(y=gr)) +
  geom_point(data = leyenda, aes(x = value, color = name), size=5) +
  geom_dumbbell(mapping = aes(x=Episcan_I, xend=Episcan_II, y=gr),
                colour="#b2b2b2",
                colour_x ="#9fb059",
                colour_xend = "#edae52",
                size=5.0,
                dot_guide = TRUE,
                dot_guide_size = 0.15,
                dot_guide_colour = "#b2b2b2",
                show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_rect(data=groups_COPD_1, aes(xmin=70, xmax=75, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="#efefe3") +
  geom_text(data=groups_COPD_1, aes(label=diff, y=gr, x=72.5), fontface="bold", size=5) +
  geom_text(color="#edae52", size=5, vjust=-1.2, hjust= 0.5,
            aes(x=Episcan_II, y=gr, label=percent_first(Episcan_II))) +
  geom_text(color="#9fb059", size=5, vjust=2, hjust= 0.5,
            aes(x=Episcan_I, y=gr, label=percent_first(Episcan_I))) +
  
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(-3, 76)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.100,0)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("#9fb059", "#edae52") ) +

  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_line(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "top",
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_blank())+
  labs(
    title ="Change of respiratory symptoms between Episcan I and Episcan II in COPD patients",
    x="Percentage (%)", y="Respiratory symptoms",cex.lab=1
  )
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Fenómeno Patricio. Muchas gracias por tu acertada y muy bien explicada respuesta. Funciona muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

Los diagramas de dumbell los diagramas de puntos conectados son una excelente manera de visualizar el cambio en algo a lo largo del tiempo para varios grupos. Los diagramas con mancuernas son una excelente alternativa a los gráficos de barras agrupados, ya que los diagramas con mancuernas utilizan mucha menos tinta en el papel y son mucho más fáciles de entender.

Podemos usar los paquetes de extensión ggplot2 para hacer un gráfico con mancuernas. Sin embargo, en esta publicación aprenderemos cómo hacer un gráfico con mancuernas en R usando ggplot2 desde cero. Usaremos el conjunto de datos gapminder y haremos un gráfico con mancuernas que muestre cómo cambia el valor de la esperanza de vida en varios países desde el año 1952 hasta el 2007.

Comencemos cargando los datos de gapminder y el conjunto tidyverse de paquetes R para hacer diagramas con dumbell.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_bw())
```

Cargamos los datos de gapminder de la página de github de datavizpyr.com.

```
gapminder <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datavizpyr/data/master/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv")
head(gapminder)
 
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
##   country      year      pop continent lifeExp gdpPercap
##   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 Afghanistan  1952  8425333 Asia         28.8      779.
## 2 Afghanistan  1957  9240934 Asia         30.3      821.
## 3 Afghanistan  1962 10267083 Asia         32.0      853.
## 4 Afghanistan  1967 11537966 Asia         34.0      836.
## 5 Afghanistan  1972 13079460 Asia         36.1      740.
## 6 Afghanistan  1977 14880372 Asia         38.4      786.
```

Para hacer un gráfico dumbell, vamos a crear un subconjunto de los datos de solo dos años, 1952 y 2007. Además, nos enfocamos en uno de los continentes en los datos de gapminder.

```
df <- gapminder %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1952,2007)) %>%
  filter(continent=="Asia")
```

Con estos datos podemos hacer un gráfico con mancuernas para comparar el cambio de la esperanza de vida de 1952 a 2007 para todos los países asiáticos. Hacemos un gráfico con mancuernas trazando puntos para cada punto de tiempo y los conectamos con una línea para cada país. Para conectar los puntos, necesitamos especificar qué filas o países deben conectarse. Creamos una nueva variable que especifica el grupo correspondiente a cada país.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(paired = rep(1:(n()/2),each=2),
         year=factor(year))
```

Ahora tenemos los datos listos en el formato para hacer un gráfico con mancuernas.

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
##   country     year        pop continent lifeExp gdpPercap paired
##   <chr>       <fct>     <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>  <int>
## 1 Afghanistan 1952    8425333 Asia         28.8      779.      1
## 2 Afghanistan 2007   31889923 Asia         43.8      975.      1
## 3 Bahrain     1952     120447 Asia         50.9     9867.      2
## 4 Bahrain     2007     708573 Asia         75.6    29796.      2
## 5 Bangladesh  1952   46886859 Asia         37.5      684.      3
## 6 Bangladesh  2007  150448339 Asia         64.1     1391.      3
```

Primero hagamos un diagrama de barras agrupado para mostrar el cambio en la esperanza de vida de cada país entre dos años.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= lifeExp, y= reorder(country,lifeExp), fill=year)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge")+
  labs(y="Country")
```

Podemos ver que la gráfica de barras agrupada está bastante ocupada y no es fácil entender los patrones en los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gráfica de barras agrupada con ggplot2

#### Gráfico dumbell con ggplot2

Podemos hacer un gráfico con dumbell usando ggplot2 con la función geom_line () y geom_point (). Es muy similar a nuestra publicación anterior sobre la conexión de puntos con una línea , pero esta vez tenemos variables de carácter / categóricas en el eje y. Tenga en cuenta el argumento de grupo dentro de aes () de la función geom_line (). Conecta los puntos con una línea.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= lifeExp, y= country)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = paired))+
    geom_point(aes(color=year), size=4) +
    theme(legend.position="top")
```

Ahora tenemos el diagrama de mancuernas básico hecho con ggplot2 desde cero. Comparando esto con el diagrama de barras agrupado, podemos ver cuánta tinta hemos ahorrado con el diagrama de mancuernas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Reordenar el diagrama de mancuernas con ggplot2

Podemos reordenar la gráfica con mancuernas por valores de esperanza de vida usando la función reordenar () para facilitar la lectura de la gráfica.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= lifeExp, y= reorder(country,lifeExp))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = paired))+
    geom_point(aes(color=year), size=4) +
  labs(y="country")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Personalización del gráfico dumbell con ggplot2

Personalicemos el gráfico con mancuernas para mejorarlo. Primero cambiamos el color de la línea a gris para que podamos resaltar el cambio entre dos puntos.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(paired) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= lifeExp, y= reorder(country,lifeExp))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = paired),color="grey")+
    geom_point(aes(color=year), size=4) +
  labs(y="country")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Agregar colores al gráfico dumbell con ggplot2

Personalicemos aún más el gráfico con mancuernas cambiando los colores de los puntos en el gráfico. Usamos scale_color_brewer () para especificar la paleta de interés de Rcolorbrewer . También cambiamos el tema ggplot2 a theme_classic () que mantiene el tema simple sin las líneas grises en el fondo.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= lifeExp, y= reorder(country,lifeExp))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = paired),color="grey")+
    geom_point(aes(color=year), size=6) +
  labs(y="country")+
  theme_classic(24)+
  theme(legend.position="top") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Accent", direction=-1)+
```

Obtenemos una gráfica dumbell mucho mejor que muestra el cambio en la esperanza de vida con mayor claridad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Tu respuesta no soluciona el problema específico que tengo, ya que mi problema no es que no sepa hacer este tipo de gráfico sino darle el formato que necesito. No obstante gracias por la respuesta